# Convert PHP DateTime format to Moment.js

Tags: javascript

I am writing a javascript prototype for a string that will accept a PHP DateTime Format and convert it to a Moment.js DateTime Format. However, I am having a problem building the final string. I basically have it working, but I don't know how to keep the normal symbols. The problem with my code is I basically split the string by any non-alpha character. This means when I rebuild the conversion it does not include the other character. I am not sure how to fix that problem. My code is below

```
String.prototype.toMoment = function() {
    var items = this.split(/[^A-Za-z]/);
    var returnItem = "";
    var conversions = {
        'd': 'DD',
        'D': 'ddd',
        'j': 'D',
        'l': 'dddd',
        'N': 'E',
        'S': 'o',
        'w': 'e',
        'z': 'DDD',
        'W': 'W',
        'F': 'MMMM',
        'm': 'MM',
        'M': 'MMM',
        'n': 'M',
        't': '',
        'L': '',
        'o': 'YYYY',
        'Y': 'YYYY',
        'y': 'YY',
        'a': 'a',
        'A': 'A',
        'B': '',
        'g': 'h',
        'G': 'H',
        'h': 'hh',
        'H': 'HH',
        'i': 'mm',
        's': 'ss',
        'u': 'SSS',
        'e': 'zz',
        'I': '',
        'O': '',
        'P': '',
        'T': '',
        'Z': '',
        'c': '',
        'r': '',
        'U': 'X',
    };

    for (var item in items) {
        returnItem += conversions[items[item]];
    }

    return returnItem;
}
```

for example if I use the follow code `moment().format('m/d/Y H:i:s'.toMoment())` it does work and converts the returns string to `MMDDYYYYHHmmss`. The problem is I need it to return `MM/DD/YYYY HH:mm:ss`. Any help would be appreciated, Thanks!

Comment: can you just add `/` into conversion ?

Comment: nope, I am done, I should just do `.split('')` and then write an if statement that checks if the item is in the conversion list, if so convert, if not add the item to the string

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of splitting, you may try to replace the placeholders with new placeholders:

```js
String.prototype.toMoment = function() {
  var conversions = {
    'd': 'DD',
    'D': 'ddd',
    'j': 'D',
    'l': 'dddd',
    'N': 'E',
    'S': 'o',
    'w': 'e',
    'z': 'DDD',
    'W': 'W',
    'F': 'MMMM',
    'm': 'MM',
    'M': 'MMM',
    'n': 'M',
    't': '',
    'L': '',
    'o': 'YYYY',
    'Y': 'YYYY',
    'y': 'YY',
    'a': 'a',
    'A': 'A',
    'B': '',
    'g': 'h',
    'G': 'H',
    'h': 'hh',
    'H': 'HH',
    'i': 'mm',
    's': 'ss',
    'u': 'SSS',
    'e': 'zz',
    'I': '',
    'O': '',
    'P': '',
    'T': '',
    'Z': '',
    'c': '',
    'r': '',
    'U': 'X',
  };
  
  return this.replace(/[A-Za-z]+/g, function(match) {
    return conversions[match] || match;
  });
}

console.log('m/d/Y H:i:s'.toMoment());
```

Comment: This would also work, I will test to see which of the two answers performs better. I like the way yours looks more though. lol

Comment: Your's runs about 10-15% faster, I will mark yours as an answer as soon as stack overflow allows me. Thank you for the elegant response.

Comment: This kind of approach is probably best in terms of flexibility and speed.

Answer (score 0):

I should just do `.split('')` and then write an if statement that checks if the item is in the conversion list if so convert, if not add the item to the string

```
   String.prototype.toMoment = function() {
        var items = this.split('');;
        var returnItem = "";
        var conversions = {
            'd': 'DD',
            'D': 'ddd',
            'j': 'D',
            'l': 'dddd',
            'N': 'E',
            'S': 'o',
            'w': 'e',
            'z': 'DDD',
            'W': 'W',
            'F': 'MMMM',
            'm': 'MM',
            'M': 'MMM',
            'n': 'M',
            't': '',
            'L': '',
            'o': 'YYYY',
            'Y': 'YYYY',
            'y': 'YY',
            'a': 'a',
            'A': 'A',
            'B': '',
            'g': 'h',
            'G': 'H',
            'h': 'hh',
            'H': 'HH',
            'i': 'mm',
            's': 'ss',
            'u': 'SSS',
            'e': 'zz',
            'I': '',
            'O': '',
            'P': '',
            'T': '',
            'Z': '',
            'c': '',
            'r': '',
            'U': 'X',
        };

        for (var item in items) {
            if (conversions[items[item]] != undefined) {
                returnItem += conversions[items[item]];
            }else{
                returnItem += items[item];
            }
        }

        return returnItem;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Yet another slight variation that works. You can always just do a full split but add the non alpha-numeric characters you want to your translation lookup like so:

```js
String.prototype.toMoment = function() {
    var items = this.split("");
    var returnItem = "";
    var conversions = {
        'd': 'DD',
        'D': 'ddd',
        'j': 'D',
        'l': 'dddd',
        'N': 'E',
        'S': 'o',
        'w': 'e',
        'z': 'DDD',
        'W': 'W',
        'F': 'MMMM',
        'm': 'MM',
        'M': 'MMM',
        'n': 'M',
        't': '',
        'L': '',
        'o': 'YYYY',
        'Y': 'YYYY',
        'y': 'YY',
        'a': 'a',
        'A': 'A',
        'B': '',
        'g': 'h',
        'G': 'H',
        'h': 'hh',
        'H': 'HH',
        'i': 'mm',
        's': 'ss',
        'u': 'SSS',
        'e': 'zz',
        'I': '',
        'O': '',
        'P': '',
        'T': '',
        'Z': '',
        'c': '',
        'r': '',
        'U': 'X',
        '/': '/',
        ':': ':',
        ' ': ' '
    };

    for (var item in items) {
        returnItem += conversions[items[item]];
    }

    return returnItem;
}

console.log('m/d/Y H:i:s'.toMoment())
```

It really depends on what you want to do and what kind of control over the result you need.

Comment: This would work, but I think @31piy probably has the best all-around solution, it seems to even handle things like when some just rights 'Tuesday' into the string.

Comment: Yeah, I saw his answer just before I posted mine and could see that regex replace was the tool of choice, but thought I'd still post my two cents anyway.